# Flutter TZDateTime returning current time

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, timezone, flutter-local-notification

I am working with [https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) and trying to add a `zonedShedule`-Notification. For that I need [TZDateTime](https://pub.dev/documentation/timezone/latest/timezone.standalone/TZDateTime-class.html). The problem is that it is always retuning the UTC-Time... But I actually need the **ESCT**.

To get the current time I am using this line:

```
final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
```

I couldn't find anything to **convert TZDateTime to the current Local Time**... I am happy for every help!
Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

When initializating the plugin, initialize the time zones, too.

```
tz.initializeTimeZones();
final String timeZone = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZone));
```

Install package [flutter_native_timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone) to get your local time zone. Then it should work.